# Make 2nd page blank when render as PDF

Tags: pdf, css, flying-saucer

I have varying content tables in my visual force page. There will be only one table in first page. But when it overflows, it should extend to 3rd page instead of 2nd page.

I am also having a running header on all pages. So even if I use a dummy div with full page height, running header will be visible in second page.

If there was a selector only for second page or nth page like :first, it would have been easy with a full height margin for the 2nd page.